# Overloading methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, overloading

```java
class Overload{

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[]  number={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};   
    int [] num={1,2,3,4,5};
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    sum = f(number);   
    int sum1= f(num);
    System.out.println("The sum is" +sum + ".");
    System.out.println("The sum is" +sum1 + ".");
  }

  public static int f(int[] value) {
    int i, total = 0;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
      total = total + value[ i ];
    }
    return (total);
  }

  public static int f(int... x) {
    int i, total = 0;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
      total = total + x[ i ];
    }
    return (total);
  }

}
```

While compiling the above program I'm getting the error as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>javac Overload.java
Overload.java:30: error: cannot declare both f(int...) and f(int[]) in Overload
public static int f(int... x)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how markdown works on SO

Answer (score 4):

```
public static int f(int... x)
```

is nothing but: -

```
public static int f(int[] x)
```

with only difference that it does not necessarily needs an argument to be passed. And when you pass individual elements, they are converted to an array internally. So, you are actually passing an `array` only.

Whereas the later one needs an argument. An empty array at the least.

And both the methods are eligible to be invoked, if you are passing an array as argument.

So the call:

```
f(new int[] {1, 2});
```

can be made to both the methods. So, an ambiguity is there.

---

However, `f(5)` call can only be made for the first method. Since, `5` cannot be assigned to an array type.
So, the ambiguity only occurs when you are passing an array.

Comment: That's not really a good description of varargs. It's not like an optional parameter - it's an array parameter where the values can be specified individually.

Comment: to elaborate, Java converts varargs to an array underneath the covers, and you cannot have two methods with the same name and signature.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Yeah that's correct. I've edited my post quoting that part.

Comment: @RohitJain brother can u give the correct program coding that runs. Because when i call f(5) its still gives me error

Comment: @Praveen.. You won't be able to run the code, because it will not compile at all. Even though it would work for `f(5)`, it's not sure that you won't use an `array` parameter to invoke that method. So, it is considered as duplicate method. Try removing each method, and make a call `f(5)` on each of them indivually. You will see that `array` parameter fails and `var-args` successfully accepts the argument.

Comment: Okay @RohitJain. I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

your **compiler** thinks that the **method which takes variable arguments as an argument** might be the same as an **method which takes an array as an argument**. i.e., it thinks there are duplicate methods with the same number of arguments, which contrays overloading rules.

```
public void m1(int[] arr){

}

public void m1(int...i){

}
```

are basically same.the only difference is **var-args** can accept any number of int variables

Comment: That's because underneath it all, *there are* duplicate methods.  The `...` is just syntactic sugar; Java turns it into an array when compiling.

Comment: @cHao that is what my intention was. :) i am just lacking terminology i guess :P

Comment: And `var-args` must be the last parameter in a method, that would make a big difference.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yepp, thats an useful tip :)

Comment: It's not a tip, it's how Java language was designed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i know that, what i meant was its a good point to add in the answer. anyhow, that aint the case here :)

Answer (score 0):

The method signature is the same. Thus overload is impossible. Change the method signature.

There's a definition of method signature in Java from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature#Java_2).

> In the Java programming language, a method signature is the method name and the number and type of its parameters. Return types and thrown exceptions are not considered to be a part of the method signature.

In your code you have two methods with the same signature `f(int[] value)`. Another function uses `int...` as an argument, but it's equivalent to `int[]`.

Comment: you are wrong. method signature is same but return type is different then it is also called method overloading.

Comment: No, if a method signature is the same, the code just won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Method overloading is a feature of java that allows you to more then one method having the same name but different argument list

**METHOD OVERLOADING IS ALSO KNOWN AS STATIC POLYMORPHISM**

```
Argument list must be differ 
 1) Numbers of Parameters "not the same parameters"
 2) Data type of parameters "does not have the same datatype of parameters" 
 3) Sequence of Datatype of parameters "its may be possible to change the sequence the of datatype."
```

The method overloading have the same argument then it must be the return type is different suppose

```
 public class Test
 {

   public int printVal(int i,int j)
   {
     System.out.println("Integer Return type")
      return i*j;
   }

   public double printVal(int i,int j)
   {
     System.out.println("Double Return type")
      return i*j;
   }

 }
```

In the above class we have the two method one have int return type and another have double return type so that can be possible in method overloading.

**Sequence of datatype it means**

```
public class Test
{
  public void display(String surname ,String name)
  {
     System.out.println("Surname = "+surname);
     System.out.println("Name    = "+name);

  }

  public void display(String name,String surname)
  {

     System.out.println("Name    = "+name);
     System.out.println("Surname = "+surname);

  }
}
```

in above example we have two method as a same datatype but its sequence is differ this case is also called method overloading..